# How to merge traindata file in tesseract?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Hello everyone,
               Is there any way to merge or combine traindata files for different fonts and user them in Tesseract-OCR?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beginning Tesseract 3.02, you don't need to merge or combine traineddata files. The command is as follows:

```
tesseract image.tif out -l eng+spa
```

Comment: @nguyengq Hello nguyenq, you seem to have a very good understanding of tesseract and I was wondering if you would be so kind to take a look at very short tesseract question of mine? It is similar to this question but I think the command is a little different. Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420800/combine-trained-tesseract-files-into-one