# combine trained tesseract files into one

Tags: java, macos, ocr

I am using the most recent version of Tesseract on my Mac. I have one eng.traineddata in one folder and one eng.traineddata in another folder. I wish to combined my traineddata files into one big trained font file.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I have read somewhere that the -l command may be what I need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tesseract does not look for language data at two different folders. What you can do is rename one of them, e.g., to `eng1.traineddata`, and then specify them as `-l eng+eng1` option to the `tesseract` command.

Comment: so just to verify, if I did what you said, the EXACT command would be: tesseract -l eng+eng1

Comment: Also, Just to elaborate, I am compiling this from my mac for iOS. I have it working it just fine on iOS, but the hope is to combine these two separate trained files into 1 traineddata to put into my xcode project.  Thank you for your help btw!

Comment: The exact command would be: `tesseract imagefile outfile -l eng+eng1`. Since Tesseract project does not release the original training source, combining traineddata files option is not available as we would like to have.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but the command you gave above those not merge each traineddata into one correct? instead that command simple does a reading of an "imagefile" within a terminal? So my question is, if I am doing this for objective-c, is it possible to use both traineddata files then? Thanks again, will accept

Comment: That command was for the command-line execution. It does not combine but tells Tesseract engine to use two language data packs. In objective-c, you can specify it in the `Init` method as follows:
`tesseract->Init([dataPath cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], "eng+eng1");`

Answer (score 1):

i also tried for that but it seems possible only if we are creating traineddata file by compiling multiple images at the same time .
here is detailed procedure ....

"https://printalert.wordpress.com/2014/10/28/tesseract-training-more-fonts/"